# is there drier code to make a mean out of 8 columns

Tags: r

Is there a simpler and drier code to do this:

```
dfg$CD44low_rep <- rowMeans(dfg[,c('CD44low_rep1', 'CD44low_rep2')], na.rm=TRUE)
dfg$CD44hi_CD69low_rep <- rowMeans(dfg[,c('CD44hi_CD69low_rep1', 'CD44hi_CD69low_rep2')], na.rm=TRUE)
dfg$CD44hi_CD69hi_CD103low_rep <- rowMeans(dfg[,c('CD44hi_CD69hi_CD103low_rep1', 'CD44hi_CD69hi_CD103low_rep2')], na.rm=TRUE)
dfg$CD44hi_CD69hi_CD103hi_rep <- rowMeans(dfg[,c('CD44hi_CD69hi_CD103hi_rep1', 'CD44hi_CD69hi_CD103hi_rep2')], na.rm=TRUE)
```

Comment: With variable names this long I would probably use numeric indexing instead of column names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the column names doesn't have a pattern.  Make the column names as a `list`

```
lstnm1 <- list(c('CD44low_rep1', 'CD44low_rep2'),
            c('CD44hi_CD69low_rep1', 'CD44hi_CD69low_rep2'),
             c('CD44hi_CD69hi_CD103low_rep1', 'CD44hi_CD69hi_CD103low_rep2'),
            c('CD44hi_CD69hi_CD103hi_rep1', 'CD44hi_CD69hi_CD103hi_rep2'))
nm2 <- c('CD44low_rep', 'CD44hi_CD69low_rep',
     'CD44hi_CD69hi_CD103low_rep', 'CD44hi_CD69hi_CD103hi_rep')
```

and now, loop over the `list` with `lapply`, apply the `rowMeans` and assign the output to new columns

```
dfg[nm2] <- lapply(lstnm1, function(nm) rowMeans(dfg[nm], na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: Thank you @akrun , I was hoping to use something simpler, such as list(c(dfg[,1], dfg[,5]), is this possible?

Comment: @user432797 you can use either index or column names.  I generally don't use index because sometimes column names can change or the order may change resulting in a different output